# Messing with this little python Recursion function?

Tags: python-3.x

I made this Recursion Function in python just a try to make a login prompt that if `Ctrl+C` is pressed, shouldn't terminate the program but i was unable to guess why `if` statement is not working in it! When run, it always takes input even the condition is satisfied. Shouldn't it exit the program when correct pswd is typed? Here is my code...

```
import sys

def lock():
    try:
        pswd = input('Enter your password : ')
        if pswd == '123':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            lock()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        lock()

lock()
```

It should terminate the program when `pswd == '123'`. But result is :

```
Enter your password : 6237
Enter your password : 123
Enter your password : 123
Enter your password : 123
Enter your password : kj
Enter your password : 123
Enter your password :
```

Even if the pswd is correct, it keep asking password!
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Remove the recursive calls and just use a print statement to see if it works, the put back the recursive call. You don't need recursion. A while loop would do and would be clearer.

Comment: Works fine for me on `Python 3.7.5`.  Note that if you have trailing whitespace (the single newline will be consumed by input) you won't match.

Comment: As an aside, you will get recursion errors on too many incorrect passwords, and in general it will be more idiomatic to just use a while loop here

Comment: try using `exit()` or `quit()`. they do the same thing as sys.exit()

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's nothing wrong with your code. It works just fine for me on `Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) [GCC 8.3.0] on linux`

Just make sure you don't have any trailing white-space at the end of the password prompt.

Try this:

```
import sys


def lock():
    try:
        pswd = input('Enter your password : ').rstrip()
        if pswd == '123':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            lock()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        lock()


lock()
```

Output:

```
Enter your password : abc
Enter your password : 123 
Process finished with exit code 0
```